# Error while using Memory mapped files

Tags: c#-4.0

I have two EXE. Parent Exe and Child EXE.
My Parent EXE is creating memory mapped file on file1 using function "MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(C:\file1.txt,FileMode.Open,"Map1")". Name of the mapped memory is Map1.
Now i am trying to access the same mapped memory "Map1" in Child Exe with function "MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("Map1")".

While doing this i am getting an Error "Unable to find the specified file."

what should i do to Avoid this error and use the Map1 in child exe.

I'm using *VS2010*.

Comment: My crystal ball sez: If one of these EXEs is a service then you need to use `@"Global\Map1"`

Comment: No All these EXE are Console application which are running independently.